# How to export backup of database to text file

Tags: java, postgresql

How can I export my database into a text file ? I mean all of the SELECTs and INSERTs commands which has been written etc. And how can I restore that backup in future?
I've writting a simple gui interface in java and I want to add a button EXPORT_BACKUP and I want it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

for Database structure and db data (INSERTs) you may use `pg_dump` utility. I don't know what you mean when you wish to save SELECTs. Do you need to save logs?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. No , no SELECTs only INSERTS. And how can i use that pd_dump to export into a text file , and how can i restore after it ?

Comment: `pg_dump` is an utility from Postgres suite, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html for options and usage examples. This utility allows you to dump an existing Postgres database (its structure and/or data) and later restore it with `pg_restore`. Basically it's what you need to complete the task.